Sent FormData to flask route with javascript fetch
I have a button that submits a vote to flask. The flask route returns the updated votes count in json. I use javascript fetch to update the innerHTML on the button. However, fetch response receives html tags with json instead of plain json.
form
<form class="d-inline" id="vote_post" action="/post/22" method="post">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjU4OGEyYTNhMjNmZjhmMTllZjhhYjhlYzgyODFiOTM0NTIzNjZjMWYi.ZtEFxg.XTO0k9Ijne-QNcI2sliKLi4s2KM">
    <input id="" name="input_id" type="hidden" value="22">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm border border-dark-subtle px-1 py-0" id="vote_post_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="vote_post" style="font-size: .65rem;">0</button>
</form>

flask route
@bp.route('/post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post(id):
    post = db.first_or_404(sa.select(Post).where(Post.id == id))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('submit') == 'vote_post':
            vote = db.session.execute(sa.select(PostVote).where((PostVote.user_id == current_user.id) & (PostVote.post_id == id))).scalar()
            count = post.votes_count()
            if vote is None:
                vote = PostVote(user_id=current_user.id, post_id=id)
                count += 1
                db.session.add(vote)
            else:
                count -= 1
                db.session.delete(vote)

            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({"votes": f"{count}"})

javascript
let post_form = document.getElementById('vote_post');

function sendVote() {
    let postData = new FormData(post_form);
    let url = {{ url_for("main.post", id=post.id)|tojson }}

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: postData,
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
            // this console never prints
            console.log(data);
            voteBtn.innerHTML = data["votes"];
      })
      .catch(console.error);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        document.getElementById("vote_post").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // Cancel the default action
            sendVote();
        });
    });

Console error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
Promise.catch
sendVote    @ 22:956
(anonymous) @ 22:601

Resolved. I needed to add the button name/value to reach the flask route.
postFormData.append("name", document.getElementById("vote_post_btn").name);
postFormData.append("submit", document.getElementById("vote_post_btn").value);


I would say you code isn't reaching your return statement, and what you're actually returning is an HTML response, probably the debugger output. Put some breakpoints in your code and step through to see what is happening when you POST your data.

Can you post the complete response?

The form data you're sending won't include the submit button name / value. You'll need to append that manually

@Phil, I added the button name / value. It worked. Thanks
